# How to align text when the middle is bold?

Tags: autohotkey, vertical-alignment, typography

[I have a script](https://gist.github.com/ooker777/3b2a5edacb7224ffd1f0b6ea27ca6f1b) that needs to have an emboldened word. If I use:

```
Gui, Add, Text,, % "Dispassionated Concentration: " 
Gui, font, bold
Gui, Add, Text,x+0, % FormatMinutes(dc)
Gui, font
Gui, Add, Text,, % "Non Focused："  FormatMinutes(NonFocused)
                           . "`nIdle Time："  FormatMinutes(IdleTime)
                           . "`nTotal Time："  FormatMinutes(TotalTime)
```

then the result is like this:

[image]

If the line is:

```
Gui, Add, Text,Y+0, % "Non Focused："  FormatMinutes(NonFocused)
```

[image]

If it's `x-0 Y+0`:

[image]

How to align the text?

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
Gui, Add, Text,xs Y+0, % "Non Focused："  FormatMinutes(NonFocused)
```

[image]

See [Gui - Syntax & Usage: Positioning and Sizing of Controls](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm#PosSize). Admittedly I just try and error without actually understand what they do.